# $l^p$ sequences and convergences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $p,q \ge 0$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$

> Prove that $x \in l^p$ if and only if $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{y_jx_j}$ converges for all sequences $y\in l^q$

The direction $\implies$ is an application of hölders-inequality. How do I show the other direction ? Would appreciate any hints/help

Comment: Can you do the case $p=q=2$?

Comment: Look at this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4121410/application-of-closed-graph-theorem-for-l2-space/4121455#4121455)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly $p,q$ must be greater or equal to $1$.

Observe that if $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{y_jx_j}$ is convergent for every $y\in \ell_q$. Then $x_n\to 0$. Indeed, if not, then there exists a constant $c>0$ so that $|x_n|>c$. We can assume that $|x_n|>c>1$, by considering the sequence $\tilde{x}_n=\frac{x_n}{c-\epsilon}$, where $c>\epsilon>0$, for a suitable, fixed $\epsilon$.  Then for the sequence $y_n= \frac{1}{c^2}$ we have that $y\in \ell_q$ but  $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{y_jx_j}> \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{c}$ which diverges.

Now set $y_n= \frac{|x_n|^p}{x_n}$ if $x_n\neq 0$ and 0 elsewhere. Then eventually $|y_n|<1$ if $p>1$ and $|y_n|=1$ if $p=1$ and thus $y\in \ell_q$ in any case. Finally, observe that $y_nx_n= |x_n|^p$.